# concatenation of a context-free language

Tags: grammar, regular-language, context-free-language, pumping-lemma

If A is a language over {1,2,3}. Using A and the string variables p and q, we mathematically define the language B over {0,1,2,3}:

B = { p0q1 | p is empty or is a string in A, and q consists of one or more 2}

What is the smallest language class that B belongs to if:
a) There is a (terminating) algorithm that recognizes A.
b) A is a context-free language.

I have no clue could someone help me? I think that the answer to b) is that B belongs to the context-free language but I am not sure.